# git pull with gzip files in repo?

Tags: git, gzip, minify

I have a repo that contains my minified css/js files.  Some of them are gzipped.  When i go between staging and production doing push and pulls it tries to auto merge and fails on the gz ones citing it cannot auto merge binary files.

Is there a way to tell git to never try to merge a certain directory but rather only push that directories changes when a push request is made?

Any other ways you guys go about this?

Thanks!!

UPDATE:

I tried putting the following in .gitattributes

```
*.gz merge=keepTheir
```

And still getting this whenever I push: (mind you, someone else pushed before me and updated files into that repo)

```
Auto-merging public/assets/upload.css.gz
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/assets/upload.css.gz
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you define the `keepTheir` script, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267? The `.gitattributes` is just there to declare what script need to be executed on merge. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp/930495#930495 for a more detailed example.

Comment: Note: other "copymerge" strategies exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267

Comment: dumb me, i did not.  But now that I understand that my next question is, what paths are being produced by git $3 and $2?.... And also what if I wanted to make a keepOurs strategy script?  Would I do mv -f $2 $3?

Would keep ours make sure that it uploads to the repo my latest changes and keep my local copies intact the way they are?

Comment: if you want to keep your local copy intact, a `keepOurs`is better ;) That is what http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp/930495#930495 describes

Answer (score 3):

If you need the content you want to push to overwrite (instead of merge) the destination, you can define a custom merge driver in `.gitattribute` file in order to specify how you want the `*.gz` files to be merged.

See [this answer as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435020/right-way-of-tracking-a-sqlite3-binary-file-in-git/5435079#5435079).

```
.gitattributes

*.gz merge=keepTheir
```

(based on "[git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267)")

Comment: update question w/ examples.  Still running into problems.  I'd appreciate any guidance you can give me please.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to ignore the minified version because they are just a minified representation of the full files?

Include the filenames in `/.gitignore` and commit a change adding this file. Git will stop tracking changes to the minified de-facto-copies uselessly.