# Using Bitbucket for existing project

Tags: django, git, version-control, virtualenv, bitbucket

I have an existing django project on my local machine (in virtualwrapper). How do I add it to the Bitbucket?

Let say my django project is like this:

```
project
  --manage.py
  --apps
  --db.sqlite3
  ...
```

So should I do 'git init' under 'project' directory? 
Since it is develop in the virtualwrapper, so I think only the project files will be pushed to the Bitbucket, is that right? If I want to develop the project on a different computer, and want to pull the project files from Bitbucket, how should I do it? I mean should I create another virtual environment in my new machine, install django and necessary pakcages before import the files from bitbucket?

I am new to git, so I don't know what is the best to do it.

Comment: Sorry, too broad. We can't and won't teach you Git here. You would be better off reading a Git tutorial like the one the fine folk at Atlassian [put up](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial), or the [free Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book). Then ask if you don't understand a specific problem. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590688/is-it-bad-to-have-my-virtualenv-directory-inside-my-git-repository) answers your specific question about virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So should I do 'git init' under 'project' directory?

Yes, but after that, don't add everything.
Create a `.gitignore` file first, where you declare the files that shouldn't be versioned (the one that are generated)

Then add and commit: that updates a local repo.
you can easily link it to an existing empty BitBucket repo:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/myproject.git
git push -u origin master # to push changes for the first time
```

---

Normally, [you wouldn't store a binary like db.sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5435020/6309) in a *source* repo.
But this [blog post](http://ongardie.net/blog/sqlite-in-git/) suggests a way to do so through

> In a `.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes` file, give Git a filename pattern and the name of a diff driver, which we'll define next. In my case, I added:

```
db.sqlite3 diff=sqlite3
```

> Then in `.git/config` or `$HOME/.gitconfig`, define the diff driver. Mine looks like:

```
[diff "sqlite3"]
    textconv = dumpsqlite3
```

> I chose to define an external dumpsqlite3 script, since this can be useful elsewhere.
>   It just dumps SQL to stdout for the filename given by its first argument:

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 $1 .dump
```

Comment: Thanks. Oh yes, you were right. I just exclude the db file to be committed.