# What's a good way (or tool) to version control a SQLite database (schema only)?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, version-control, windows-7

Can anyone suggest a good way (or tool) to version control a SQLite database (schema only)?  I'm trying to version control a SQLite database and the only option I can find involves using GIT to version control the whole file, but I'm not interested in the data at this point, just the schema changes.

Any suggestions?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Are you trying to track changes for development or is this something you are trying to incorporate in to an application?

Comment: I'm trying to track changes for development.  Trying to find something that works very similar to Redgate's SQL Source Control tool.

Answer (score 29):

I have a two fold answer.  If your sqlite is light enough and infrequently updated, you can add it into the repository without too many repercussions/issues.

But readablity goes down for diffs since it is stored as a binary.

### sqlite3 git diff

Here is how to get git to show you diffs nicely:

https://gist.github.com/peteristhegreat/a028bc3b588baaea09ff67f405af2909

```
git config diff.sqlite3.textconv 'sqlite3 $1 .dump'
echo '*.db diff=sqlite3' >> $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.gitattributes
```

Now when your sqlite db file changes you can see the change with `git diff`.

If you wanted to only see the diff of the schema, you just change `.dump` to `.schema` and it should only do the create calls and skip the inserts.

### sqlite3 conversion in and out of the repository with clean/smudge

If you want your db file to get pushed into the repository as sql instead of as a db, you can use the clean/smudge mechanisms in git.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion

https://github.com/gilesbowkett/git-smudge-and-clean

I haven't tried it yet, but basically whenever you run across a file that is a db, git commits the stripped down version of the file (as sql commands) using the `sqlite3 $1 .schema` export.  And then when you checkout that file from your database, it gets converted back to a db using `cat $1 | sqlite3`.

### sqlite3 always keep the newest file

[Right way of tracking a sqlite3 binary file in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435020/right-way-of-tracking-a-sqlite3-binary-file-in-git)

```
.gitattributes

mysqlite3.db merge=keepTheir
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: On my setup, the git diff gave an error `Error: near "/": syntax error
fatal: unable to read files to diff`.  The fix was to move `sqlite3 $1 .dump` to a separate shell script and refer to it from textconv setting.

Comment: sounds like you have a permissions issue or the file doesn't exist.  Have you tried just typing `sqlite path/to/filename.db .dump`

Comment: Same problem as @Eero. This worked instead: `git config diff.sqlite3.textconv 'f() { sqlite3 "$@" .dump; }; f'`

Comment: I got the clean/smudge part of your answer running. The tricky part is: you really can not work with %f, i.e. the file itself, you have to work with stdin/stdout. You can find a working example here: https://github.com/Udopia/gbd-data. Just replace .dump by .schema if you do not need the data.

Answer (score 4):

There is a command line utility documented here [here](https://www.sqlite.org/sqldiff.html) on SQLite.org called sqldiff.exe. It provides various options including comparing schema. To configure git to use sqldiff instead of the built in diff tool check out this discussion: [How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program). Unfortunately it looks like its not a trivial task.

Edit: 
It looks like the only way to get the sqldiff tool is to download the full source (all the way at the bottom of the downloads page) and compile it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, sqldiff "does not (currently) display differences in TRIGGERs, VIEWs...".  I have several of those I need to version control also.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I've been tracking a 13MB / 20k row SQLite database in Git using the Makefile excerpted below. Two files, `schema.sql` and `data.sql` are stored in Git and can be `diff`ed as text files per usual.

```
SQLITE=sqlite3
SCHEMAFILE=schema.sql
DATAFILE=data.sql
DBFILE=my_database.db
TEMPDB=temp.db

dump: $(DBFILE)
    @$(SQLITE) $(DBFILE) .sha3sum >sha3_before
    $(SQLITE) $(DBFILE) ".schema --indent" | grep -v sqlite_sequence >$(SCHEMAFILE)
    $(SQLITE) $(DBFILE) .dump | grep ^INSERT | grep -v sqlite_sequence >$(DATAFILE)
    @rm -f $(TEMPDB)
    @cat $(SCHEMAFILE) $(DATAFILE) | $(SQLITE) $(TEMPDB)
    @$(SQLITE) $(TEMPDB) .sha3sum >sha3_after
    @cmp sha3_before sha3_after
    @rm sha3_before sha3_after
    @rm $(TEMPDB)

database:
    rm -f $(DBFILE)
    cat $(SCHEMAFILE) $(DATAFILE) | $(SQLITE) $(DBFILE)
```

The `dump` step generates new `schema.sql` & `data.sql` files, then generates a new database from them and compares the SQLite `.sha3sum` of the database before and after to validate that it is getting an accurate copy.

In my application, this database is used as a read-only `.db` file (essentially a product catalog), so it has a single source of updates.  My update cycle is:

```sh
   make database
   # update the data in the database as needed
   make dump
   git commmit schema.sql data.sql
```

The only problem I'm having with this process is that the `.schema` command sometimes adds a formatted comment field after `CREATE VIEW ...` statements each time I generate it and doesn't remove the old one. So there's a gradual accretion of comments in my `schema.sql` file. I mitigate that by viewing the git diff and manually adjust before committing.

Answer (score 2):

From the sqlite documentation, you can extract the schema information from the sqlite_master hidden table. (https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master)

You can save this content in a text file in GIT, this should give you a way to track changes to the schema.