# How do I store a sqlite database as plaintext in git, in a lossless way?

Tags: database, git, sqlite, text, git-filter

I want to store (small) sqlite database files as plaintext in my git repos. The goal is to make it easier to use traditional version-control features (easy-to-grok diffs, mergeability, ...) on such files. I have seen this approach thus far:

```
git config filter.sqlite3.clean 'sqlite3 %f .dump'
git config filter.sqlite3.smudge 'sqlite3 %f'
echo '*.db filter=sqlite3' >> .git/info/attributes
```

Is this a viable option? What are the failure modes? What are the costs? What other options exist?

Update: This causes weird checkout problems. Avoid it unless you're quite proficient with git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38271631/7976758

Comment: @phd I am very much interested in the data of the database, but I'll take a look at that anyway. Thanks.

Comment: The linked answer talks more about data (`.dump`) than just schema (`.schema`) and is easily adaptable anyway.