# Project management of both mixed and binary files

Tags: version-control, project-management

we develop software which also includes a lot of art assets (binary files). We would like to version control our source code, but do not keep track of binary files changes (artists works separately and upload new art assets). However, one checkout should produce full tree of both source and art. This is needed because we want to run continuous integration system afterwards (nightly builds, testing). What you could recommend? Maybe any of those web hosted apps allows one to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing binaries in an [artifact repository](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/04/what-is-a-repository/) like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/): it offers a simple referential based on the filesystem, with simple directories based on a naming convention.
This is very easy to maintain.

Such a model is linked to the source control through a *declarative* process: you declare in a file (`pom.xml`) what version of which artifact you need for your specific version of your code.
That `pom.xml` file is managed like the rest of your sources.